# how to optimized this image processing replace all pixels on image with closest available RGB?

Tags: ios, image-processing, core-graphics, core-image

Im' trying to replace all pixels of input image with closest available RGB. I have a array contain color and input image. Here is my code, it give me an output image as expected, BUT it take very LONG time( about a min) to process one image. Can anybody help me improve the code? Or if you have any other suggestions, please help.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(sourceImage),CGImageGetHeight(sourceImage)), NO, 0.0f);
 //Context size I keep as same as original input image size

 //Otherwise, the output will be only a partial image
 CGContextRef context; 
 context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

 //This is for flipping up sidedown
 CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.imageViewArea.image.size.height);
 CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);



        // init vars
        float d   = 0;                           // squared error
        int idx = 0;                             // index of palette color
        int min = 1000000;                       // min difference
        UIColor *oneRGB;                         // color at a pixel
        UIColor *paletteRGB;                     // palette color



        // visit each output color and determine closest color from palette
        for(int y=0; y<sizeY; y++) {
            for(int x=0; x<sizeX; x++) {
                // desired (avg) color is one pixel of scaled image
                oneRGB = [inputImgAvg colorAtPixel:CGPointMake(x,y)];


                // find closest color match in palette: init idx with index
                // of closest match; keep track of min to find idx
                min = 1000000;
                idx = 0;

                CGContextDrawImage(context,CGRectMake(xx, yy, 1, 1),img);
            }
        }

        UIImage *output = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        self.imageViewArea.image = output;
```

Comment: Which part of your code takes longest (the loops, `UIGraphics` or `CGContext` function, etc.) ? Profile your code.

Comment: What is the code for `ColorDiff`? Also, the convention is to name methods with initial lower case letters, ex: `[self colorDiffWithPalette:paletteRGB forRGB:oneRGB]`

Comment: @Jacob:I think the loops is talking most of time consume.

Comment: @CocoaFu: the ColorDiff if find different between two input UIColor. And the name of method was myColorDiff, but when I edit the name, I forgot to change it back to lowercase. Thanks. Do you have any other suggestion to improve the time consuming for the code?

Comment: Hard to tell without the code to `ColorDiff` which is called in the inner-most loop. Can that code be improved by organizing the data palette?

Comment: @CocoaFu: I just added myColorDiff. FYI, the myColorDiff is returned squared Euclidean distance. Please help.

Comment: My understanding is that Lab colorspace is better for calculating color differences in that it more closely represents human perception.

Comment: Adding to my comment .. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678457/best-algorithm-for-matching-colours/

Comment: @PeterM, if RGB color distance is too slow then Lab is certainly too slow even if it might generate slightly better results. Once a faster algorithm is in place it might be something to look into.

Comment: @MarkRansom It all comes down to what the requirements really are.  I mentioned the Lab to prompt whether the OP wasn't optimizing the wrong thing.

Comment: The comment says `myColorDiff` is returning the sum of the squares which would be correct, but I don't see any squaring in the actual code.

Comment: @MarkRansom, thanks to point that out for me. I missed square of each components

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar question (with no definitive answer), but the answer there has the code for directly accessing pixels from an image.

[Quantize Image, Save List of Remaining Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474732/quantize-image-save-list-of-remaining-colors)

You should do that rather than use CG functions for each get and set pixel.  Drawing 1 pixel of an image onto another image is a lot slower than changing 3 bytes in a array.

Also, what's in ColorDiff -- you don't need perfect diffing as long as the closest pixel has the smallest diff.  There may be room for pre-processing this list so that for each palette entry you have the smallest diff to the nearest other palette entry.  Then, while looping through pixels, I can quickly check to see if the next pixel is within half that distance to the color just found (because photos tend to have common colors near each other).

If that's not a match, then while looping through the palette, if I am within half this distance to any entry, there is no need to check further.

Basically, this puts a zone around each palette entry where you know for sure that this one is the closest.

Comment: Nice optimization for early exit, especially when used against the previously found palette entry. For the linear search it's only going to cut the search time in half on average, probably not enough to be a viable solution by itself. Note that when comparing the square of the distance you want to use 1/4 of the value, not half.

Comment: I think you get more than half benefit because of color runs of nearly the same color happening fairly often in real images.   I think the real solution is to use direct memory access to the pixels -- the other idea probably won't come close to that one in effectiveness.

Comment: I just started to test it work with array of RGB or not. Then my goal is read thru pixels of input image and find all closest tile images to replace. It means I can't really just change RGB.

Comment: I don't think I was very clear - I was splitting your solution into two parts. If you manage to skip the linear search, or in your words "looping through the palette", you're going to get fantastic savings. That's the case when you have a run of similar colors. However once you start searching the entire palette it's totally random where the match will be so the savings will be half or even less.

Comment: Mark ah, I see that now.  @user1139699 the code you have ends up coloring just one pixel, so it's equivalent to just changing the RGB of a pixel -- what do you mean by tiles?

Comment: Yes, I find a closest available RGB in my array to replace the current pixel on input image.

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer is to use a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree#Nearest_neighbour_search) or some other [Octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) structure to reduce the number of computations and comparisons that have to be done at each pixel.

I've also had success with partitioning the color space into a regular grid and keeping a list of possible closest matches for each part of the grid. For example you can divide the (0-255) values of R,G,B by 16 and end up with a grid of (16,16,16) or 4096 elements altogether. Best case is that there's only one member of the list for a particular grid element and no need to traverse the list at all.

Comment: I understand what u saying. That's why I scale down my processing image to lower resolution, then do processing